# Program crashes at printing string vector

Tags: c++

I'm making a program that write and read "reminders", and i when i'll print a string vector with the "reminders" it crashes and i don't know why this happens, it can compile, but it crashes at running, thanks for anyone that tried to help. Here's the code:

```
vector<string> v = ReadFile();
for(vector<string>::iterator i = v.begin();i != end();i++) {
    cout << *i << '\n' << endl;
}
```

Another "version" of the code, that crashes too:

```
vector<string> v = ReadFile();
for(int i = 0;i < v.size();i++) {
    cout << v[i] << '\n' << endl;
}
```

Sorry if exits another thread with the same problem.

PS: I'm using MinGW as compiler

Complete code here:

```
#include <iostream> // Basic IO
#include <fstream> // File IO
#include <stdlib.h> // free()
#include <vector> // For using vectors
#include <string> // For strings
#include <dirent.h> // Read files from folders
#include <windows.h> // GetCurrentDirectory()

void WriteFile(string desc) { 
    ofstream write(desc.c_str());
    write << "Created on: " << __DATE__ << " " << __TIME__ << "\n";
    write.close();
    printf("\nReminder saved with success");
}

vector<string> ReadFile () { 
    vector<string> reminders; 
    DIR *dir; 
    struct dirent *ent;
    LPSTR buffer;
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, buffer);
    if((dir = opendir(buffer)) != NULL) { 
        while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) { 
            reminders.push_back(ent->d_name);
        }
        closedir(dir);
        free(dir);
        free(ent);
        free(buffer);
    } else {
        printf("\nError at reading folder or empty folder");
    }
    return reminders;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> v = ReadFile();
    for(int i = 0;i < v.size();++i) {
        cout << v[i] << '\n' << endl;
    }
    return  0;
}
```

Comment: Your above code looks correct and there could be problem in somewhere else may be ReadFile().... You should check other functions in your program.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but did you mean `v.end()`?  Or could that be your problem?  Also, recommend changing `i++` to `++i` since most iterators support that one more commonly.  I don't think that's your issue, though, since `vector<t>::iterator` supports both.

Comment: Well, when i only create the vector, it runs fine(ReadFile() works fine), but when i print that causes the crash. And when i use ++i instead of i++ in the first code, the compiler gives me a long error(that i can see the start of the error), in the second code it crashes. :/

Comment: Present a complete, compileable example which demonstrates the problem. Just because a problem doesn't manifest until a particular piece of code is added, does not mean that the just added code is the problem.

Comment: @DJPeterson All iterators support both forms of ++. ++i may be slightly more efficient than i++, depending on the compiler.

Comment: Compile with debugging symbols on, run with a debugger, and show us the line where the segfault happens.

Comment: @Neil Kirk True for STL iterators.  But not necessarily custom iterators provided by yourself or a third-party :)

Comment: @DJPeterson Then the library is bad, why would you provide one and not the other?

Comment: @AndyG Sorry but i don't know nothing about debugging(im newbie), i tried gdb buti dont know what i do :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
LPSTR buffer;
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, buffer);
```

`LPSTR` is a typedef for `char *`, or something similar. However, the `GetCurrentDirectory` function expects to be passed a buffer that is already allocated. Change to:

```
char buffer[MAX_PATH+1];   // or TCHAR
GetCurrentDirectory(sizeof buffer, buffer);
```

Also, you should not call `free(buffer)` because you did not `malloc` it.

I believe `free(ent);` and  `free(dir);` are both errors too, as those functions return pointers into memory which is managed by the runtime library.  In general, only call `free` on things that you malloc'd, or the function's documentation tells you that you need to `free`.

Comment: But i have a question, when i create a variable, it doesn't implicit alloc memory for the var, so why i don't need to free it?

Comment: You only `free` things that you `malloc`.  When you create a variable, you automatically allocate space to store that variable, and that space is automatically released when your function ends.